# How to retrieve the event start time in google calendar using the java api?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-calendar-api

I have searched a lot and couldnt find the info that i am looking for. I am trying out a google calendar application in google app engine with java. I am unable to figure out how to retrieve the start time of a calendar event. The 'when' field in the CalendarEventEntry class does not exist ( i checked older posts and tried to follow those answers). The getTimes() method returns a list of DateTime entries but i am not sure what those are. Here is a snippet of my code -

```
CalendarEventFeed resultFeed = service.getFeed(Films_Url, CalendarEventFeed.class);                              
for (int i = 0; i < resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) 
{
CalendarEventEntry entry = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i);               
Entity Film = new Entity("Films_and_Movies",Film_and_Movie_key);                       
Film.setProperty("title",entry.getTitle().getPlainText());                  
Film.setProperty("time",entry.getUpdated().toUiString());                   
DatastoreService datastorE = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService(); 
datastore.put(Film);                
}
```

entry.getUpdated() does return a DateTime object but it is the time when the event was updated, not the start time. I tried using entry.when.startDate but 'when' does not exist in the CalendarEventEntry class as I said earlier. I tried using EventEntry instead of CalendarEntry but I dont think the former does not exist anymore in recent updates. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: Tam wszystko działa.
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995495/google-calendar-api-java

estudiosoftware
Poland